# HTML Button if script not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a script that will run a different function every time the button is clicked in a ordered way. So for example when the button is clicked it will run the tick1 function first, then when pressed again it will run the tick2 function. This is my attempt but it will only run the tick1 function. Many thanks, Simon

```
<script>
var trafficktick = 1;
function tick() {
    if (trafficktick = 1) {
        tick1()
        var traffictick =  trafficktick + 1;
    } else if (trafficktick = 2) {
        tick2()
        var traffictick = trafficktick + 1;
    } else {
        var trafficktick = 1;
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: = is assignment, == compares

Comment: youre also rewriting traffictick continually plus you should use `===` for compare.

Comment: http://jshint.com/ Paste your code in and run it

Comment: Above comments are correct and will solve the issue. As a sidenote, using an array or similar will make coding this way more extensible, sicne you won't have to write an if clause for every function you add.

Comment: Why are people posting answers if there already are identical ones previously posted?

Comment: Using == instead of === is perfectly acceptable, by the way.

Comment: @Feathercrown In this case yes. Not always

Comment: @Weedoze 99.9% of the time, it's useful to convert. Personally, I have never used ===, but it is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In the if condition use `===` and not `=`

Comment: `===` (type comparision)

Comment: @Xenos But why? What's the problem with ==?

Comment: Because `' \n\n' == 0` is `true`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript#523650 and https://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/

Comment: You are right type comparison is very important even though it means nothing to this question, It is still better to always use it as best practice.

Comment: I changed the comment

Answer (score 1):

Multiple errors where done :

1. You were using `=` (assign a value) instead of `===` (comparaison)
2. You miswrote `trafficktick`
3. Instead of doing `var trafficktick = trafficktick + 1;`. Simply do `trafficktick++;`

```js
var trafficktick = 1;

function tick() {
  if (trafficktick === 1) {
    //tick1();
    console.log("Call tick1");
    trafficktick++;
  } else if (trafficktick === 2) {
    //tick2();
     console.log("Call tick2");
    trafficktick++;
  } else {
    trafficktick = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="tick()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some errors in your JavaScript, try something like this:

```
<script>
    var trafficktick = 1; // Use var only here

    function tick() {

        // Use '==' or '===' depending on your logic operation to 
        // compare equality
        if (trafficktick == 1) { 

            // You want that? You can comment this call and call
            // it outside from an element (for example)
            tick1(); 
            traffictick ++; // Only '++' and no 'var' 

        } else if (trafficktick == 2) {

            tick2();
            traffictick ++; // Only '++' and no 'var'

        } else {

            trafficktick = 1; // No 'var'

        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: I still get the same problem, it stays only runs tick1 and never tick2 :l

Comment: Nvm i figured it out thanks :D

Comment: @ReaP If you can not get it working you can try my working snipper answer

Comment: @ReaP your tick1() and tick2() calls the tick() function? The tick() function only route the calls based on the count and sum it (and by consequence you'll be in another condition in the next time) or set 1 again. Take care about the way you are working with the calls, we don't have it in this snippet.